# Oneof with same type in C++ Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I've a message like:

```
message Foo {
    oneof Value {
        string a;
        string b;
        string c;
        string d;
        string e;
    }
}
```

How can I write and then read `oneof` field by avoiding to write something like:

```
if (choose_a)
    write a
else if (choose_b)
    write b
...

if (a is set)
    read from a
else if (b is set)
    read from b   
...
```

Comment: Change the proto to contain only one string field (and perhaps add an enum field if necessary)?

Comment: if it is either a string or a string, then quite likely it is just a string ;). Why do you want to use `oneof` ?